# postgres query to get first row based on multiple copies of some columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a table -

```
A        B       C  
1        3       5  
1        3       7  
1        3       9  
2        4       3  
2        4       6  
2        4       1
```

here there are multiple copies for the same combination of A and B. for each combination I want back the first entry of it.
so the result for this table i want to be-

```
A        B      C  
1        3      5  
2        4      3
```

How can I do this in postgres sql?

Comment: Please define "first" (there is no natural order in a table). And what is the primary key? [This related answer may be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you can define "first" in terms of a sort on a, b, and c you want `DISTINCT ON` for this.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON ("A", "B")
  "A", "B", "C"
FROM Table1
ORDER BY "A", "B", "C";
```

E.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ca16/1

See [`SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) for more on `DISTINCT ON`.

---

If you have made the serious mistake of assuming SQL tables have an inherent order, you're going to need to fix your table before you proceed. You can use the PostgreSQL `ctid` pseudo-column to guide the creation of a primary key that matches the current on-disk table order. It should be safe to just:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

as PostgreSQL will tend to write the key in table order. It's not guaranteed, but neither is anything else when there's no primary key. Then you can:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON ("A", "B")
  "A", "B", "C"
FROM Table1
ORDER BY id;
```

(Edit: I don't recommend using `ctid` in queries baked into applications. It's a handy tool for solving specific problems, but it's not really public API in PostgreSQL, and it's not part of the SQL standard. It's not like `ROWID` in Oracle, it changes due to vacuum etc. PostgreSQL is free to break/change/remove it in future versions.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can *sort* of do this.  SQL tables have no concept of ordering, so you really need a column to specify the order.  The following returns an arbitrary row from each group:

```
select distinct on(a, b) a, b, c
from table t
order by a, b;
```

Normally, you would use something like:

```
select distinct on(a, b) a, b, c
from table t
order by a, b, id desc;
```

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted "first" as "first in a, b, c" order, but that's not given in the question.